# Can you run out of moves in Bejeweled Blitz?

Tags: bejeweled-blitz

I've wondered this for a while, but it never came up until just now. If you're playing Bejeweled Blitz, is it possible to run out of moves? I *think* I just did (hint button didn't reveal anything), but I'm not certain.

In normal Bejeweled games, running out of moves either ends the game or gets you a newly-scrambled board. In Blitz, if you can, and you do, what happens?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out it is possible to run out of moves in Blitz. It's not easy, it's not common, and Blitz really does seem to try and ensure that you have a move available at all times. But like any algorithm, it's not perfect.

It's happened to me at least four or five times since I posted this question. When you click the "hint" button, nothing will highlight -- that's because you're out of moves. Oddly, the game will not notify you that you're out of moves. My hunch is that because of the trouble they went through to prevent it from happening, they just didn't expect to ever encounter that issue. (But of course, I don't work for PopCap, so I'm just guessing there.)

When it happens, you have no choice but to either wait out the clock or restart the game.

Comment: *"But like any algorithm, it's not perfect."* - I think you mean *"hueristic"* here.  Non-heuristic algorithms *do* perfectly solve the problem they're meant to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I even saved the screen where it was impossible to move just kept asking for hints until the clock ran out!

Comment: Could you post the image?

Answer (score 2):

It does happen. Done it to me several times and yes, mostly if I'm running at blazing speed.

Answer (score 2):

May 31, 2014.  This is a screen cap of my game at 20 plus sec remaining (start time..by time I hit Prnt Scrn obiously shorter).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run out of moves in Bejeweled Blitz (the HINT button will always show you a match). This is because each gem that falls is specifically chosen so that this never happens.

It CAN happen however, that your only move is the newest gem(s) that just fell, so it's very possible that you are stuck working at the very top (low points) for a long time until something cascades down far enough so that you can work in the middle or bottom.

Comment: I don't see how that could be possible - it's easy to construct a board with three empty spaces at top, in which no matter what new blocks are dropped there are no possible matches.

Comment: You just contradicted yourself. The three empty spaces at the top could all be filled with the same color and have a match.

Comment: My point here is that out of all the games I've played and what I hear from other pros is that there is never no matches to be had. The jem-dropping algorithm _isn't_ random.

Comment: I have to disagree. I've had it happen now on multiple occasions. Hint button shows *nothing.* On one occasion it happened with 28 seconds left -- I had a long time to evaluate the board, click the hint button multiple times, etc. I do think the algorithm attempts to make that extremely rare, but I've personally had it happen.

Comment: @John so then... my answer is incorrect. Post yours, because it _is_ possible to run out, you've just proven by example. : )

Answer (score 1):

I've had it happen so many times now..usually when I'm playing the game really fast. I suppose it just doesn't work out that the next jewels it gives will leave the player with no moves sometimes.