# Why do I never get "no more moves" in non-Classic bejeweled?

Tags: bejeweled-3

I'm playing Bejeweled on my iPhone. My classic games usually end in "no more moves". However, this has never happened in Diamond Mine, Lightning, or Butterflies - not yet, anyway. My question is: why does it happen in Classic but not in the other game modes? Is the jewel-generating algorithm rigged to supply you with matches in some modes, but not in others?

I'm basically trying to determine the 'luck' aspect of the game vs. the 'skill' aspect. If the generated gems are generated with the exact same ratios, why does it happen with differing frequencies according to the game mode?

Comment: I don't know anything about those modes, but some modes are designed to never run out of moves.

Comment: How do they guarantee that? do they always generate a match whenever new gems fall down?

Comment: @Claudiu - Yes.  The algorithm that generates new gems tries to ensure that a match is possible with the gems it generates.  See [this similar question for Bejeweled Blitz](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/can-you-run-out-of-moves-in-bejeweled-blitz).

Comment: This means that it sometimes gets easier when you "run out of moves", because all of your new moves will be concentrated in that small area near the top, where the new gems fell in.

Answer (score 3):

Classic mode is the only game mode in Bejeweled that ends in "no more moves".

> ...nearly every mode in Bejeweled 3 drops gems specifically so you’ll
> never run out of matches – Lightning, Butterflies, Diamond Mine, Ice
> Storm, Time Bomb, Gold Rush, Stratamax, Alchemy, Balance, Buried
> Treasure, Poker and Zen all function this way. The one mode that doesn’t:
> **Classic mode**.

[source](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626171906/http://www.unwinnable.com/2012/06/21/game-over/)